# If I want to rollback to an older commit How do I find the <tag/branch/commit id>

Tags: git, github

Where in Github can I find the `<tag/branch/commit id>` of a commit I want to rollback to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **GitHub** you can browse the Commit History, branches and tags (GitHub calls it "Releases" ) for a repository from the project home page.

Just navigate to `https://github.com/<Username>/<Repository Name>`.

See the highlighted areas below -

[image: GitHub Repository with highlights for information.]

Answer (score 4):

`git log` allows browsing the history. And at the top left of the Github repo page, you can click on "46 commits" to see this log.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Open git bash and type `gitk`
2. Type `git log --oneline`
3. Search for your commit if you know the message

   `git log --oneline | grep "your search phrase"`
4. Use sourcetree if you are not so good with command line
   http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/download/

Comment: I think the downvote on this answer might be a little bit overkill. There's nothing in it that's factually incorrect, though I do disagree with the poster's recommendation of using a GUI instead of just learning to use Git from the command line.

Comment: Question asks "Where in Github..." - This answer doesn't include anything about GitHub.